# c++ - Calling a function for all members of a specific type

Tags: c++

I have a class `C` with a member function `f`.  Users may create their own classes with several `C`'s as members.  I'd like to be able to call `f` for every member of type `C` in a user-defined class.  The problem is I can't figure out how to implement this without the users having to provide a function like this:

```
void UserClass::callFonEveryCmember(void) {
    c1.f();
    c2.f();
    ...
}
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: What if your users don't want to call `f` on all members? Let the users provide their own, it's less confusing than a hack that gets inside their stuff and calls w/e. Suggest that they place their `C`s in some collection (like it appears they should anyway).

Comment: Use an array of functions.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't have reflection like e.g. C# if that's what you're after. What I've done in the past is to generate C++ code from a class description and then also generate reflection code with it. I.e. your users would be making class descriptions rather than classes.

The short-term solutions I see are 
1) Have a function like you describe above
2) Rather than separate member, use one member with a vector of c's.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserClass
{
    ...
    vector<C*> v;
}

void UserClass::callFonEveryCmember(void)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        v.at[i]->f();
    }
}
```